# Attempt do define a limit of a function for surreal numbers?

Tags: limits, analysis, surreal-numbers

I am attempting to define "the"/a limit for surreal functions:

Write for surreal numbers $x,p$ and $f$ a function: (Each surreal number $x$ is mapped to a unique surreal number $f(x)$.)

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow p} f(x) = L \iff \exists L \text{ surreal }  \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \hat{\delta}>0: \forall 0 < \delta \le \hat{\delta}: \text{ If } x = \{p-\delta|p+\delta\} \text{ then } L = \{ f(x)-\epsilon | f(x)+\epsilon \}$$

I could show - maybe I am being too optimistic - that $L$ is unique, if it has the property above.

The proof mimics essentially the same as in the definition of the limit in real case.
My question is:

1. Can this be independently verfied?

If it is not asked too much:

2. If $\lim_{x \rightarrow p} f(x) = a$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow p} b(x) = b$, do we have:  $\lim_{x \rightarrow p} f(x)+g(x) = a+b$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is a surreal function ? What is a surreal number ?

Comment: @Fred: For function, I have defined it in the question. For Surreal number are found by Conway and defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any ordered field, there is a notion of limit (hence also derivative) for functions using the usual "$\delta$-$\varepsilon$" definition. It is somewhat well-known that the corresponding topological and analytic notions retain many of the elementary properties of topology on real numbers (e.g. addition and multiplication are continuous), but *none* of the important ones (e.g. Rolle's theorem fails).

Your definition is not the same as that I am alluding to, and it is not too interesting for the following reason:

For each surreal number $p$, for all sufficiently small $\delta>0$, we have $p=\{p-\delta \ | \ p + \delta\}$. To see this, note that the function $\delta \mapsto p+\delta$ is injective, so for cardinality reasons, for small enough $\delta \neq 0$, the birth day (or length) of $p+\delta$ cannot be less than that of $p$. More precisely, assume for contradiction that for each positive ordinal $\alpha$, there is a non-zero number $\varepsilon_{\alpha}$ smaller in absolute value than $\frac{1}{\alpha}$, such that $p+\varepsilon_{\alpha}$ has birth day smaller than the birth day $\beta$ of $p$. Using this, we can define an injection $\mathbf{On}^{>0} \rightarrow \mathbf{No}(\beta+1)$ where $\mathbf{No}(\beta+1)$ is the *set* of numbers of birth day $\leq \beta$, and $\mathbf{On}^{>0}$ is the proper class of positive ordinals, which cannot be.

So if $L= \lim_p f$, then in particular we have $L=\{f(p) -\varepsilon \ | \ f(p) +\varepsilon\}$ for all $\varepsilon >0$. For sufficiently large $\varepsilon >0$, we have $0=\{f(p) -\varepsilon \ | \ f(p) +\varepsilon\}$, so $L=0$. But then $f(p)$ must be zero as well because $0=L$ should be as close as we want to it.

And we can see that conversely, if $f(p)=0$, then $0$ is indeed the limit of $f$ at $p$.

In other words, your definition is equivalent to $f(p)=0$, with $0$ being the limit if that occurs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know, where I can read about the limit you mention in your answer and Rolle's theorem?

Comment: @mathoverflowUser You can find James Propp's paper "Real-analysis in reverse" on arxiv.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: What do you mean with "cardinality reasons"?

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Comment: Is $L:=\{ f(p-\delta_1)-\epsilon_1,f(p+\delta_1)-\epsilon_1|f(p-\delta_2)+\epsilon_2,f(p+\delta_1)+\epsilon_2\}$ where the $\delta,\epsilon$ run through $>0$ any sensible definition?